# Use case diagrams for an MVC design pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have this UML use case diagram; I am wondering if in a use case diagram it is appropriate or required to represent the MVC design pattern i.e. controllers, models explicitly within the diagram itself.

I feel the purpose of a use case diagram is to represent the typical interactions the user will perform on the application thus keeping it as simple as possible, without controllers is the ideal approach. This is how I have structured the diagram below.

Should the diagram be good as it is or should it follow the MVC design pattern?

[image]

Comment: Your bubbles don't show any use case at all. You should read Bittner/Spence about use cases (or Cockburn if you like the old style). There are a number of answers here about use cases and what they mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC is a **design** pattern. A use case is an **analysis** tool. So, I think, a use case diagram showning the MVC pattern would be plain wrong.

Comment: Moreover "UseCases define the offered Behaviors of the subject **without reference to its internal structure**" and MVC is bout internal structure, so it'd be two times wrong ;-)